# Separating Convergence Proof in Compact-Open topology to Open Subset and its Complement

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and equip $C(X,Y)$ with the compact-open topology *($X$ may be assumed to be Hausdorff if necessary)* and let $\emptyset \neq U\subseteq X$.  Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}},f$ be functions in $C(X,Y)$.

If $f_n|_U$ converges to $f|_U$ in $C(U,Y)$ *(for the compact-open topology)* and $f_n|_{X-U}=f|_{X-U}$ then can we conclude that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $C(X,Y)$?

If not, what should be assumed in addition?

Comment: Is $U$ open or just any subset?

Comment: @JustinYoung I relaxed the assumptions so that outside of $U$ $f_n=f$.  Does this make is easier?